# Why are there two common-mode chokes on AC input?

Tags: ac-dc, common-mode-choke

This is a part of an AC/DC converter schematic from TI.

There are two common-mode chokes on the AC input side.

I have no idea why two CMCs (L100, L101) are used.

Could anyone explain this?

[image]

Comment: If the datasheet or application note does not tell you the design desicions to end up in a certain design, we can't guess any better, other than it is required to meet specification. Maybe one big was too large and two smaller ones fit better. From which document the schematics are taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extra reactive element creates another pole in the transfer function and provides additional attenuation of unwanted frequencies.  Kind of a "one wasn't enough and three wouldn't fit" situation.  See: https://www.mouser.com/pdfDocs/doc191_CMFiltDesign.pdf for an in-depth explanation.